# Which one is better? Backpacking from Paris to Italy or Spain? (Finding a good route with low budget)

Tags: france, italy, paris, backpacking, milan

I'm backpacking from Paris to Milan (or Spain - Low budget). I want some places in this path to visit and stay specially nice villages. I have 6-7 days for this travel (after I'm going to Milan, Venice, and Rome if I have Italy in my route not Spain) for 4-5 days. I can use train for a part of the route. I don't have any plan for Spain but based on your recommendation I cane change the route to Spain

- Is this a good plan to have this travel in France or it is better to have more time in Italy (or Spain?) for back-packing?

I want have combination of all things as possible like places other tourists going to visit and other places that have beautiful sights (villages, jungles and sea - specially villages). What is your suggestion for best places in France (or Italy, or Spain?) in this route?

Comment: Paris, Milan, Venice ... don't really sound "low budget"

Comment: Duration of visit of these cities is low. maximum two days in every main city :-) Any better recommendation? + I'm trying to use `couch-surfing` and `aribnb` to decrease the cost and visit new people. Is this a good idea?

Comment: + I can go to Spain instead of Italy.

Comment: That's a good choice toi, but then you have to open another question.

Comment: @AndréPeseur . I changed question title. thanks.

Comment: Paris to Venice will be more expensive IMHO.  Close voting as opinion-based

Comment: How do you travel? there are more and more cheap bus options opening in this region. Check for megabus and idbus lines.

Comment: @njzk2 Thank you for comment. It depends on the recommended route. I can use bust, train etc.

Comment: Milan and Venice are very expensive even for us Italians